# Can I store special symbols in a String variable?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, utf-8

I have some 48 special symbols and want to store them in a string variable. Is it possible to do this? If yes, please provide me with the solution. I am using the NetBeans IDE.

`♥ ♡ ❤ ♤ ♢ ♦ ♠ ♣ ♧ ❣ ❦ ❧ ☺ ✔ > ⌂ □ ☼ ✯ ✰ ◕ ◔ ♮ ♯ ❝ ❞ Δ ☾✽  ✾  ✿ ❁ 
❃ ❋ ❀ ∞ → •♥•  ¤  ø  „  ★ •  *  +  Ω  =  ◊  ≥  ‡  ›  …  ¤`

Above are the special symbols which i want to store, when i try it looks,

```
 public String symbols = "? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? > ? ? ? ?
 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? •?• ¤ ø „ ? • * + ? = ? ? ‡ › … ¤";
```

This is my code:

```
StringBuilder tweetText = new StringBuilder();
if(count_symbol > 50)
{
     count_symbol = 0;
}
String symbol_array[] = symbols.split(" ");  
tweetText.append(symbol_array[count_symbol]);
tweetText.append(" ");
count_symbol++;
```

Please provide some solution.

Comment: This is possible. If it's not working for you, please share your code.

Comment: If your system uses UTF-8, i imagine you could just paste them in.  Otherwise, use `\uXXXX` to represent them from ASCII etc.

Comment: `StringBuilder tweetText = new StringBuilder();
if(count_symbol > 50)
{
     count_symbol = 0;
}
String symbol_array[] = symbols.split(" ");
tweetText.append(symbol_array[count_symbol]);
tweetText.append(" ");
count_symbol++;`

Comment: String does not have any encoding as such in java. Did you mean you have a problem in setting this in netbeans ide?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think you didn't set the `character encoding` in project properties to
>   `UTF-8` that's why special symbols are converted to question marks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Inside of a String is more or less an array of `char` types. A `char` in Java is simply a value consisting of two bytes and can be set directly to a value like an `int`. Find out the value of these symbols, and of course make sure you are using the proper encoding. Make a `char` array containing these values and construct your string using the `String( char[] )` constructor or `String( char[], Charset )` if you want to specify a character set.
You might include a resource in your package that has these symbols saved, and load them into you char array with an `InputStream`. That would save you some of the work of manually entering the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
String escapedString =
            "\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005\"";
```

hey please try using escape characters